# and error xml4.dll on client machine

Tags: access-denied

When I have login on client machine and will login in Mamut I got a error say this:
OLE IDispatch exception code 0 from msxml4.dll: access is deneid. And on the modul: clssettingsxml.save.
I have set all the right permission on the right folder but with no result.
I hope some one can help me here

Thanks in advanced

Keld Rasmussen